# php json encode to data.txt file - how to prevent hotlinking?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a question regarding how I can prevent hot linking to the .txt file produced by json encode.

I run the query, and the data is written to a .txt file.  This is working great, however my concern is it would be possible to bypass the php session and link direct to the txt file.  For example. www/path/to/data/rawdata.txt?_=1415782184

```
//sql query
$response['data'] = $json;

$fp = fopen('data/rawdata.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```

I am using jquery datatables to render the data.

```
$(function() {
var $dTable= $("#datalogs").dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/rawdata.txt"
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if understood the question. Your ajax call shouldn't request the txt file, but a php page that returns the requested json AFTER checking if this is a valid session. Maybe this is stoopid, but have you looked how a REST API is constructed?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment.  Datatables uses an ajax sourced data method to read from the text file: Example: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: I don't think you can prevent anyone that has the url to your text file from reading it. If this file contains critical/user bound informations you should use a php script that reads the database and returns the result to the loggedIn/valid user and not store it anywhere. Of course this php script should contain a proper session checking. Just try to request something like rawdata.php and in this php file make a db-query and echo/json_encode the result. I'm still not sure if I understood your question, so if this is total BS to you, just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest renaming the file from .txt to .php

This way, you can protect it against hotlinking with the following php code:

```
define('AJAX_REQUEST', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!AJAX_REQUEST) {die();}
```

I have never tried that but I believe there should be no problem to do such rename...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Captain theo!

This is a nice piece of code! and combined with my included session in the php file, I believe it added increased security.

Comment: I am glad this was helpful to you! Happy coding!